# Botão dentro de um card clicável

Tags: ux

Durante o desenvolvimento vi a seguinte situação:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Onde o card é clicável e leva para o estoque do usuário, porém dentro do card tem um botão inativo, ou seja, o usuário geralmente vai clicar no botão para ir ao estoque mas isso funcionaria para qualquer parte do card.

Na minha visão o botão deveria ser clicável e o card inativo para que o usuário pudesse copiar alguma informação do card ou algo parecido.

Qual abordagem seria a mais correta?

Comment: Quando você cria um objeto com link, ele é atribuído a todos os objetos dentro dele em primeira instância. Se você conseguir editar esse cardo coloque os texto para serem clicaveis, ou faço o botão por fora do card e coloque ele por cima do card com css.

Comment: Mas o clique do card vai para um local diferente do botão detalhes ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Heurística Número 5 de Nielsen:** Previna Erros

**Heurística Número 6 de Nielsen:** Reconhecimento em vez de memorização

**Lei 5:** Basicamente vc está enganando o usuário e induzindo ele ao erro... Se vc quer que o `card` todo seja clicado não coloque um `outline` no botão, pois delimitando a área do botão parece que exclusivamente ele é um elemento clicável. Então caso o usuário clique no `card` "sem querer" e seja encaminhado para outro lugar ele vai se frustrar e ficar confuso (principalmente se não tiver uma forma fácil de voltar).

**Lei 6:** **Elementos que parece algo deve agir como o algo**, então, se algo parece um `botão` o usuário espera que ele funcione como `botão`, se um `texto é sublinhado` o usuário espera que ele seja um `link`. Muito provavelmente o usuário não vai esperar que o `card` seja um `link`, principalmente tendo um botão dentro dele.

Vc está pecando em dois erros fundamentais das Heurísticas de Nielsen, e não vou me aprofundar nos conceitos, mas sugiro que leia o link da fonte

*Fonte:* https://www.nngroup.com/articles/ten-usability-heuristics/

Uma alternativa é retirar o `outline` do `botão`, assim pelo menos vc não engana o usuário "delimitando uma área ativa" que não é real.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**OBS:** Apesar disso, se vc tem um botão não tem pq deixar o `card` todo como uma área ativa... Vc mesmo citou um problema, imagine que o usuário queira dar um `ctrl+c` de alguma coisa dentro do `card`, ele pode **acidentalmente** clicar indo para outra página... `Previna erros!`